# (Powershell) Catch "Get-WinEvent : No events were found" Get-WinEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

When I run a below command to list log by ID, it says `Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.`

How can I catch this exception and display a simple message saying "No events found".

Command which I ran-

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID="191"}
```

I tried below below but could not make it working-

```
try { Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID="191"}
    }

catch [Exception] {
        if ($_.Exception -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
        Write-Host "No events found";
                 }
    }
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a non-terminating error which won't get caught by `try`/`catch`. Use `-ErrorAction Stop`.

```powershell
try { Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName="Application";ID="191"} -ErrorAction Stop
    }

catch [Exception] {
        if ($_.Exception -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
        Write-Host "No events found";
                 }
    }
```