# Powershell: filtering out events from certain process

Tags: powershell, eventlog-source

I have quite a usual for every sysadm in task: to audit access to certain folders on fileserver during last, e.g. 1 day. But in addition I need to rule out access attempts from certain processes.

What I wrote (part of code:

```
foreach ($FileServer in $Fileservers) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Checking events on $FileServer"
    $GweParams = @{
        Computername = $Fileserver
        LogName = ‘Security’
        FilterXPath = '*[System[EventID=4656 or EventID=4663]
                       and not (EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] = 'C:\Windows\System32\fsdmhost.exe'])
                       and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 360000]]'
    }
    $Events = Get-Eventlog @GweParams
    $Events
    $Events | export-csv -path C:\usr\logs.csv
}
```

But Powershell gives me plenty of errors, and even more, ISE visually splitting this code in quite unexpected blocks. It seems to me that I am missing some of quotes and brackets, but can't figure out where?

Could somebody help me with this? Or suggest some better code?

Comment: Try using a double quoted [Here-String](https://riptutorial.com/powershell/example/20569/here-string) for the filter. `FilterXPath =@"*[System[EventID=4656 or EventID=4663] ... "@`

Comment: What does the `360000` represent?  Is that seconds?  Milliseconds?  Are you trying to get anything in the last 100 hours, or the last 6 minutes, or something else?

Comment: Darin, this is milliseconds I believe. But at this very moment I am trying to figure out how to select events with certain eventIDs, but exclude from certain process. We can forget about TimeCreated part.

Comment: Theo, thank you for tip, but thing is that I can't figure out now why with this settings I can't find even the events (that do exist) if I am removing all filters except the list of EventIDs...

Comment: You can do something similar with get-winvent -filterhashtable, although there's no "data not equal value".

Answer (score 1):

*There is more than one way to skin a cat, but there aren't any he will like.

Similarly, there is more than one way to filter events, but there aren't any I like.*

##### [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1):

*No claims that this is the best way, just the way I figured out.*

In the following code example of `Get-WinEvent`:

1. You can optionally define a remote computer via the `-ComputerName` parameter.

   - Note: When connecting to a remote computer, you may receive a "The RPC server is unavailable" error, or other errors.

     - *Fixing these errors is outside the scope of this question and answer.*
2. To filter on multiple properties, define a hash table of property names/keys and the desired value for each. In this example:

   - LogName: Set to "Security", limits to only events in the Security log.
   - ID: An array of Event IDs.
   - StartTime: Retrieve only events after this point of time.
3. Several example lines for defining multiple versions of `$StartTime` are provided, all but one line is commented out, with tail comments explaining the line.
4. The cmdlet `Get-WinEvent` pops out an alarming looking error message if it fails to find matching events.

   - This [SO tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26680177/4190564) by [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist) solves the problem by using a *try/catch* with `-ErrorAction Stop`.
5. The matching events are saved in the `$rawEvents` variable.
6. For more information, read the page on [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1).

   - Take note of the examples and the section on [`-FilterHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-5.1#-filterhashtable).

Setup our variables:

```
$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddMinutes(-2)        # Events in the last 2 minutes
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddDays(-2)          # Events in the last 2 Days
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddHours(-2)         # Events in the last 2 Hours
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddMilliseconds(-2)  # Events in the last 2 Milliseconds
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddMinutes(-2)       # Events in the last 2 Minutes
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddMonths(-2)        # Events in the last 2 Months
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddSeconds(-2)       # Events in the last 2 Seconds
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::Now.AddTicks(-2)         # Events in the last 2 Ticks
#$StartTime = [DateTime]::now.AddYears(-2)         # Events in the last 2 Years
$FilterHashtable = @{
   LogName   = 'Security';
   ID        = @(4624, 4670, 4672, 4699, 4985);
   StartTime = $StartTime
}
```

Safely execute Get-WinEvent without error, and exit if either no matchings events are found or other error:

```
try {
   # $rawEvents = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName "server.domain.com" -FilterHashtable $FilterHashtable -ErrorAction Stop
   $rawEvents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $FilterHashtable -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch [Exception] {
   if ($_.Exception -match "No events were found that match the specified selection criteria") {
      Write-Host "No events found";
   }
   exit
}
```

##### Part 2:

*Did you really think we were done?*

So, you want to filter events based on the `ProcessName` property.  Sounds easy enough, until you discover there is no such property!  No problem, all you have to do is call the `ToXml()` method of each event, drill down to the `.Event.EventData.Data` array returned by that method, check each element in the array for a `Name` property containing "ProcessName", return that element's `#text` property, **which can't be accessed in a normal way because it starts with a `#`**, and then do a comparison on it to see if it is what you want.

**Or**, you could use the following code which adds to each Event on the pipeline an `EventData` member containing all members defined by the xml the `ToXml()` method provided.  This does cause a performance hit, but it didn't seem all that noticeable when compared already existing slowness of Get-WinEvent.

```
$cookedEvents = $rawEvents |
   Select-Object -Property *, @{Name = 'EventData'; Expression = {
      $return = [PSCustomObject]::new()
      foreach ($obj in ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data) {
         Add-Member -InputObject $return -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $obj.Name -Value $obj.'#text'
      }
      $return
   }
}
```

Now, thanks to the newly added `EventData`, it is smooth sailing from this point forward and no more problems - right? Right? Oh, right! Not all events will necessarily include the `ProcessName` property in the xml, so, to play it safe, we probably should filter out events missing this property.

Same code as before, just one more line to filter out a missing property:

```
$cookedEvents = $rawEvents |
   Select-Object -Property *, @{Name = 'EventData'; Expression = {
      $return = [PSCustomObject]::new()
      foreach ($obj in ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData.Data) {
         Add-Member -InputObject $return -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $obj.Name -Value $obj.'#text'
      }
      $return
   }
} | Where-Object { Get-Member -InputObject $_.EventData -Name 'ProcessName' -MemberType Properties }
```

So, you want all events by all processes except those with a `ProcessName` of "C:\Windows\System32\fsdmhost.exe".  The following line should do it!:

```
$results = $cookedEvents | Where-Object { $_.EventData.ProcessName -ne 'C:\Windows\System32\fsdmhost.exe' }
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.  It also seems to me that now I understand how to filter output with only few details that I need in EventData.

Answer (score 0):

Taking [Event ID 4656](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4656) as an example from your code, it looks like there is a specific field with process information. You can just filter out the events based on the process name such as :

```
$events = Get-EventLog -LogName Security
$filteredEvents = $events | Where-Object { $_.Process -ne "test.exe" }
```

Assuming the property available is called "Process". I don't have access to an example of this specific ID, but you can provide one like this

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security | Where-Object { EventID -eq 4656 } | Select -First 1
```

Do not forget to remove any sensitive / PII info before answering.
Happy to follow up after that

Answer (score 0):

All right, with your help, some investigations and few cother answers to other topics I managed to create two scripts for my linking:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
Clear-Host
#List of fileservers:
$FileServers = @(
    'Server1',
    'Server2',
    'Server3',
    'Server4')

#Query settings:
$Query = @"
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=4656) or (EventID=4663)]]
     and *[System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 86400000]]]</Select>
    <Suppress Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\fsdmhost.exe') ]]</Suppress>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
"@
#before is a query for last day from time script has been run.

#$Begin = '2024-02-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'
#$End = '2024-02-02T13:00:00.0000000Z'
#Time format: YYYY-MM-DD  t HH:MM:SS.0000000Z for milliseconds

#$Query = @"
#<QueryList>
#  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
#    <Select Path="Security">
#    *[[System[(EventID=4656) or (EventID=4663)]]
#    and
#    *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='" + $Begin + "' and @SystemTime<='" + $End + "']]]
#    </Select>
#    <Suppress Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\fsdmhost.exe') ]]</Suppress>
#  </Query>
#</QueryList>
#"@

#before all commented - two additional variables and query for checking events from Begin-date to End-date.

#Parameters we need in output:
$properties = @(
    @{n='TimeStamp';e={$_.TimeCreated}}
    @{n='Object';e={$_.Properties[6].Value}},
    @{n='User';e={$_.Properties[1].Value}},
    @{n='Process';e={$_.Properties[15].Value}}
    )

#Script itslef
foreach ($FileServer in $Fileservers) {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Checking events on $FileServer"
#cycling servers

$events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $FileServer -FilterXml $Query

ForEach ($Event in $Events) {
    # Convert the event to XML
    $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()
}

#final export to c:\usr\security.csv
$Events | Select-Object $properties | Export-CSV C:\usr\security.csv -Append

}
```

I believe, it could be useful for others.